# Unable to use SQL Server Authentication with SQL Server Express 2008

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I have a simple question regarding SQL Server Authentication.

I am working with SQL Server 2008 Express which came along with VS2010. As SQL Server Express was installed along with VS2010, there was no option to enter the password for SQL Server authentication (had I gone for SQL Server 2008 Standard, I get a screen where I can enter the password).

Now when I try to create a new database with SQL Server authentication, I tells me enter the username and password which I have never created.

[image]

Where should I go from here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need to reinstall.

1. Download and install SQL Server Managment Studio (SSMS).
2. Use SSMS to connect to your server, use Windows Authentication
3. Right-click server - Properties - Security tab
4. Select "SQL Server and Windows authentication mode" click OK button
5. Right-click server - Select Restart
6. Go to node Security-Logins
7. Right-click on login "sa", select properties
8. Enter password (twice) on the general tab
9. Select Status tab
10. Select "Grant" under "Permission to connect to database engine"
11. Select "Enabled" under "Login"
12. Click OK

Comment: Nice guide (+1).
Still, if you just started using the server it's faster to simply reinstall :)
Especially if you do not have the SSMS.

Answer (score 2):

I have SqlExpress installed along with Mgmt studio express. That allows me to change the SA password.

Comment: The link to download the [Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options when installing the SQL Server 2008 Express: mixed or windows authentication. There are two textboxes below that to enter sa/password.

Try using windows authentication. But it would be probably best to reinstall the server in mixed mode with a password and username that you are going to remember.